# Phone gap + socket.io + heroku

Tags: android, cordova, heroku, socket.io

I have an appli which call a socket.io server hosted on heroku.
When i launch my app on my mobile (android) with the command "phonegap serve" i have this error :

> **[phonegap] Proxy error for url: myserverheroku:3000/socket .io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1421696372422-2 undefined [phonegap]
>   ECONNREFUSED myserverheroku:3000/socket.io/?EIO
>   =3&transport=polling&t=1421696372422-2**

Can you give some help please ?

(Sorry for my English, i'm french)

server.js file :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

http.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { message: 'Hello world' });
});
```

app.js file :

```
var socket = io.connect('http://star-wars-bluff.herokuapp.com');
socket.on('news', function (data) {
    document.getElementById('welcomeMsg').innerHTML = data.message;
});
```

index.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
        <title>Star Wars Bluff</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <h1>Star Wars Bluff</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="welcomeMsg"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script><!-- load angular -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="http://star-wars-bluff.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

config.xml file :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.heroku.star-wars-bluff" version="1.0.0" versionCode = "10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>Star Wars Bluff</name>
    <description>
        Le poker des cafards version Star Wars
    </description>
    <author email="contact@labo-web.fr" href="http://labo-web.fr">
        Labo web
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.5.0" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <!-- <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" /> -->
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon gap:platform="webos" src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
    <access origin="http://star-wars-bluff.herokuapp.com" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem.
When i tried to open url myserverheroku:3000 i had a 404.
I connect my mobile with phonegap on an ip like 1.1.1.1:3000, so when i tried to connect to the socket server, phonegap add the port 3000.

My solution is to replace :

```
var socket = io.connect('http://star-wars-bluff.herokuapp.com');
```

by

```
var socket = io.connect('http://star-wars-bluff.herokuapp.com:80');
```

But now, socket.io doesn't work very well, maybe because of angularjs.
In destop, all works fine but not on the mobile.

app.js

```
var swb = angular.module('swb', ['ngRoute', 'swb.controllers']);

swb.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/init', {templateUrl: 'partials/init.html', controller: 'InitCtrl'});
    $routeProvider.when('/welcome', {templateUrl: 'partials/welcome.html', controller: 'WelcomeCtrl'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/init'});
}]);
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('swb.controllers', ['btford.socket-io']).
factory('socket', function (socketFactory) {
  return socketFactory({
    ioSocket: io.connect('http://star-wars-bluff.herokuapp.com:80')
  });
})
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$window', '$location', 'socket', function ($scope, $rootScope, $window, $location, socket) {
    $rootScope.chat = [];
    $rootScope.players = [];
    $rootScope.player = {};
    $rootScope.slide = '';

    $rootScope.back = function() {
      $rootScope.slide = 'slide-right';
      $window.history.back();
    }

    $rootScope.go = function(path){
      $rootScope.slide = 'slide-left';
      $location.url(path);
    }

    socket.on('connected', function (data) {
        $rootScope.players = data.players;
        if(data.player)
            $rootScope.player = angular.copy(data.player);
        $rootScope.chat.push(data.message);
    });
    socket.on('disconnected', function (data) {
        $rootScope.players = data.players;
        $rootScope.chat.push(data.message);
    });
}])
.controller('InitCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'socket', function ($scope, $rootScope, socket) {
    $scope.createPlayer = function(){
        socket.emit('adduser', $rootScope.player);
        $rootScope.go('/welcome');
    };
}])
.controller('WelcomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'socket', function ($scope, $rootScope, socket) {

}]);
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="swb">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
        <title>Star Wars Bluff</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <h1>Star Wars Bluff</h1>
        </div>
        <div ng-view ng-class="slide"></div>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="http://star-wars-bluff.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/socket.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

init.html

```
<h2>Bienvenue sur Star Wars Bluff</h2>
<form name="addPlayer" ng-submit="addPlayer.$valid && createPlayer()" novalidate>
    <input placeholder="Votre nom" type="text" ng-model="player.name" required>
    <button type="submit">Jouer</button>
</form>
```

welcome.js

```
<h2>Liste des joueurs</h2>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="connectedPlayer in players"><span ng-class="{you: player.id==connectedPlayer.id}">{{player.id}} {{connectedPlayer.id}} {{ connectedPlayer.name }}</span></li>
</ul>
<h2>Infos</h2>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="info in chat | limitTo: -5">{{ info }}</li>
</ul>
```

server.js

```
// init server
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

http.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

// usefull functions
var removeByAttr = function(arr, attr, value){
    var i = arr.length;
    while(i--){
       if( arr[i] 
           && arr[i].hasOwnProperty(attr) 
           && (arguments.length > 2 && arr[i][attr] === value ) ){ 

           arr.splice(i,1);

       }
    }
    return arr;
}

// games data & functions
var types = [...];

var cards = [...];

var playersPerRoom = 6,
    players = [],
    rooms = [];

var gameReady = false;

var currentPlayer,
    currentCard,
    currentOpponent,
    currentType;

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('adduser', function(data){
        socket.player = data;
        if(rooms.length < 1){
            socket.room = 'room1';
            rooms.push(socket.room);
        }else{
            var roomNumber = Math.ceil((players.length + 1) / playersPerRoom);
            socket.room = 'room' + roomNumber;
            if(rooms.indexOf(socket.room) == -1)
                rooms.push(socket.room);
        }
        socket.player.room = socket.room;
        if(players.length < 1)
            socket.player.id = 1;
        else
            socket.player.id = players[players.length - 1].id + 1;
        players.push(socket.player);
        socket.join(socket.room);
        socket.emit('connected', {message: 'Bienvenue sur le serveur ' + socket.room, players: players, player: socket.player});
        socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('connected', {message: socket.player.name + ' est désormais connecté au serveur ' + socket.room, players: players});
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        if(socket.player){
            removeByAttr(players, 'id', socket.player.id);
            socket.broadcast.emit('disconnected', {message: socket.player.name + ' a quitté le serveur ' + socket.room, players: players});
            socket.leave(socket.room);
        }
    });
});
```

When i connect a phone, in the desktop app, the users list and the chat are updated, but on an another phone they doesn't update themselves.

Have you any ideas to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems when upgrading to phonegap ~4.2 ... downgrading to an older version solved the problem. This seems to be a phonegap bug.

Try downgrading to e. g. phonegap@3.5.0-0.20.10

```
npm install -g phonegap@3.5.0-0.20.10
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i use the utf8 module for node to encode the string which is emmited with socket.io and it works fine !